# Convert query filter expression into JSON object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

In JavaScript, there is a JavaScript package function that receives a JSON object as a filter expression, at the same time, I want to write the query filter expression in a readable way using strong typing.
So, I'd like to convert strongly-typed query filter expression into a JSON object in JavaScript.

For example:
I want to convert the following expression:

```
jsOject.LastName= "abc" && jsOject.CountryId = 1 && jsObject.CategotyId = 2
```

into JSON object as following:

```
{ 
   and: [{
      LastName: 'abc',
      CountryId : 1,
      CategotyId : 2
   }]
}
```

where jsOject is a previously declared object.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: JSON string or JS object?

Comment: How is `jsOject` defined?

Comment: JSON object like that:
{ 
   and: [{
      LastName: 'abc',
      CountryId : 1,
      CategotyId : 2
   }]
}

Comment: Please be aware that there is [no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). (I know this is a bit pedantic, but it's worth knowing)

Comment: No problems, if it's possible to convert it to a JSON string in the same format, I can deal with it.

Comment: This will never work - is it `jsOject` or `jsObject`? You use both

Comment: @DarrenSweeney What about converting query filter expression into JSON string?